# Simple Combination problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My mathematical background in school involves no probability being taught, so this question might be very straightforward to answer. 
I have five close friends and we all want to have lunch together. My school has 3 lunches, A, B, and C. We know this probably won't happen, but I was wondering what the probability would be for exactly two, three, four or five of us to have lunch together.

For any two of us to have lunch together: The chance of me getting a specific lunch A, B, or C is 1/3. I can apply this logic to two people having a lunch together as 1/9. But I know that no matter the combinations of people in lunches it is more rare for 1 person to be alone at lunch than for 2 people to be alone, but I am very unsure about my thinking.

Comment: 'Lunch together' meaning having the same lunch? Or '3 lunches, A, B, and C' meaning there are 3 different places to eat?

Comment: Shuri, can you explain how that works? Because me and 4 of my friends could be in A lunch together, one other person in B lunch, and nobody in C lunch! I'm sorry for my lack of correct wording.

Comment: @PhilTheLawyer  OK, you need to be a bit more clear as to what exactly you are asking. I thought that you were asking about the probability of 'any two of us to have lunch together'. So with 5 people eating lunch A and 1 person eating lunch B, that seems to be satisfying the claim that there are indeed at least two having the same lunch. But if it isn't, then what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Bram28 I am asking for exactly 2 people in a lunch when I say "2 people in a lunch" and same goes for 3 people in a lunch. Thank you for helping me clear this up.

Comment: @PhilTheLawyer I see what you mean now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In how many cases is each lunch being eaten by $2$ people each? (we represent this by $(2,2,2)$. Well, there are ${6 \choose 2} = 15$ ways to pick two people to eat lunch $A$, and then ${4 \choose 2}=6$ ways to pick two people to eat lunch $B$, leaving the others with lunch $C$. So that is $15*6=90$ possibilities.

As another example: how about 3 people eating one lunch, 2 other people eating a different lunch, and the last person eating the third type of lunch (this would be $(3,2,1)$? Well, let's first consider the case where the $3$ people eat lunch $A$, the next two eat lunch $B$, and the last person eats lunch $C$. There are ${6 \choose 3} = 20$ ways to pick three people to eat lunch $A$, and then ${3 \choose 2}=3$ ways to pick two people to eat lunch $B$, leaving the last person with lunch $C$. So that is $60$ possibilities. Of course, the same holds for $3$ people eating lunch $B$, 2 people eating lunch $C$, and $1$ person eating lunch $A$. Since there are $6$ different ways to change this, you get a total of $360$ possible ways for $3$ people eating one lunch, $2$ other people eating a different lunch, and the last person eating the third type of lunch.

Likewise, we can find the numbers for the different possibilities:

$(2,2,2)$: ${6 \choose 2} \cdot {4 \choose 2} = 15 \cdot 6 = 90$

$(3,2,1)$: ${6 \choose 3} \cdot {3 \choose 2} \cdot 6 = 360$ (the most likely outcome .. this happens *almost* half of the time)

$(3,3,0)$: ${6 \choose 3} \cdot 3 = 20 \cdot 3 = 60$

$(4,2,0)$: ${6 \choose 4} \cdot 6 = 15 * 6 = 90$

$(4,1,1)$: ${6 \choose 4} \cdot {2 \choose 1} \cdot 3 = 15 * 2 * 3 = 90$

$(5,1,0)$: ${6 \choose 5} \cdot 6 = 6 \cdot 6 = 36$

$(6,0,0)$: ${6 \choose 6} \cdot 3 =3$

Total: $729$ possibilities, which indeed equals $3^6$ *(sanity check!)

If you want the probabilities for these events, just divide the number of possible ways these events can take place by $729$. So, for example, $P(3,2,1)=\frac{360}{729} \approx 49.3$%

Comment: No, but if there are 4 people all in Lunch A then the other person can be in Lunch B by themselves.

Comment: What I mean was that if the system of my friends having A lunch, B lunch, and C lunch being represented by (a, b, c) could potentially range from (0, 0, 6) to (2,2,2). I don't care about specific permutations so (0, 0, 6) would mean the same as (6, 0, 0). I hope this extended information can provide any assistance.

Comment: @PhilTheLawyer OK, that's more helpful, yes. OK, so I just answered the (2,2,2) case in my Answer. Let me add the others.

Comment: Thank you so much for the excellent response and patience!

Comment: @PhilTheLawyer No problem!  I just added a little more explanation as well.